# Nodejs library without nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I integrate a nodejs library into my non nodejs project?
I am particularly needing this library: 
https://github.com/greenify/biojs-io-blast

Comment: This really depends on whether or not the package supports running in a browser. If it does then you would do the same `npm install packagename` and then compile it with browserify to get a single file.

Comment: take a look at browserify

Comment: or if your're using webpack as a build/dev environment then you can pull though all sorts of npm goodies....

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[BioJS](http://biojs.io/) uses [Browserify CDN](https://wzrd.in/) to automatically generate a single JS file for usage. Either include

`<script src="http://wzrd.in/bundle/biojs-io-blast@latest"></script>`

in your html or download the JS file via this link.

We also have a live JS Bin example [here](http://jsbin.com/fufaxezawa/edit?js,console).

Comment: Thanks! But the example is not quite working... "blast object"
null

Comment: I tried to download your "standalone" and load on a local blast xml file, but it returns null.

Comment: I updated the JS Bin link. It should work now. Thanks for spotting :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it using a Publisher/Subscribe pattern and a Queue library, such as RabbitMQ.

In the example below, the author is communicating a python script with a NodeJS one, using the RabbitMQ clients for each platform.

https://github.com/osharim/Communicate-Python-with-NodeJS-through-RabbitMQ

The code for sending from NodeJS:

```
var amqp       = require('amqp');
var amqp_hacks = require('./amqp-hacks');

var connection = amqp.createConnection({ host: "localhost", port: 5672 });

connection.on('ready', function(){
    connection.publish('task_queue', 'Hello World!');
    console.log(" [x] Sent from nodeJS 'Hello World!'");

    amqp_hacks.safeEndConnection(connection);
});
```

Then, receiving in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika
import time

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='task_queue', durable=True)


#our callback
def suscriber(ch,method , properties , body):
    print "[Y] received %r " % (body,)
    time.sleep( body.count('.') )
    print " [x] Done"
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)



channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
channel.basic_consume(suscriber, queue = 'task_queue')

print ' [*] Waiting for messages from Python. To exit press CTRL+C'
channel.start_consuming()
```

Answer (score 0):

to integrate any node library you use the package manager NPM https://www.npmjs.com/ so to integrate your library do as follow

1. open terminal
2. cd path/to/your/project_dir
3. type this line

   > npm install biojs-io-blast

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer to this question! This answer is very short though and doesn't provide much context. Please explain some of the reasoning behind it, and it will become much more useful for the asker and future readers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the more common use case. Some of the node.js libraby, i like them too much i want to use it everywhere. But this library, what i see uses core modules of node.js like `fs`. I dont think you can use it without node dependency || node binary. But as *Code Uniquely* or others folks says, if you are using webpack as a build/dev. You can try, [browserify](http://browserify.org/) `or` [BioJS](http://biojs.io/)

Answer (score 0):

The node_module which provided is kind of xml parser. You can't add nodejs library (node_module) to non nodejs programs. You can get xml parser for Blast depending on kind of programming language you are using.

For example : 
For PHP [phpBlastXmlParser](http://riadh.pfba-lab-tun.org/BlastXML) and
For java [this might helpfull](https://code.google.com/p/blast-xml-parser/source/browse/trunk/BLAST_XML_Parser/src/org/blast/parser/main/XMLParser.java?r=5)